# construction string with string builder et string format

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

Before I had a fix item that I could write directly into my code:

```
 public static string GetCsvStringFormat(int count)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{{{0}}};", i);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

    return string.Format(
        RefTypeParseExtension.GetCsvStringFormat(3),
        "No Id","Article","Amount"
    );
```

but now the item is dynamic, may be only 1 or 2 or more item.

I have tried with array:

```
string[] Tete = { "No Id","Article","Amount","IsFix"}
string temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Tete.Length; i++)
{
    if (i != Tete.Length-1) { temp += "\"" + Tete[i] + "\","; }
    else { temp += "\"" + Tete[i] + "\""; }
}
return string.Format(
    RefTypeParseExtension.GetCsvStringFormat(Tete.Length),
    temp
);
```

I have tried also with string builder:

```
public static string GetTete(string[] Tete)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();          

    for (int i = 0; i < Tete.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != Tete.Length - 1) { sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",", Tete[i]); }
        else { sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", Tete[i]); }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

both I receive the same error :

> The index (zero base) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

eventhought the result of array and string builder return exactly like it was.

Comment: Not from this code.

Comment: Also, a better line would be `string.Join(", ", Tete);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but your first code sample is working with the overload of [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts a `string` and `params object[] args` - so I think you should simply do this:

```
public static string GetTete(string[] Tete)
{
    return string.Format(RefTypeParseExtension.GetCsvStringFormat(Tete.Length), Tete);
}
```